# Flipping Control/Command in GNOME breaks Alt key in JVM

Tags: gnome, java, keyboard-layout, macintosh, intellij

I want to switch <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> modifier keys in GNOME / Debian Jessie, because I use a Macintosh laptop.

I have managed to get these changed via the `TweakTool` -> `Typing panel`, like this:

- `Ctrl key position` -> `Left Ctrl as Meta`
- `Alt/Win key behaviour` -> `Ctrl is mapped to Win keys (and the usua..)`

**But this introduces a new weird problem with the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key**, that I can at least witness in JVM applications, e.g. IntelliJ IDEA: It is not possible any longer to use any keyboard shortcut that uses the <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier.

For example the following prints the reported modifiers:

```
import javax.swing._
import java.awt.event.{InputEvent, KeyEvent}
val f = new JFrame
val p = new JPanel(new java.awt.GridLayout(3,1))
f.setContentPane(p)
val ls = Array.fill(3)(new JLabel("-"))
ls.foreach(p.add)
p.addKeyListener {
  new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter {
    def apply(i: Int, e: KeyEvent): Unit = 
      ls(i).setText(InputEvent.getModifiersExText(e.getModifiersEx))
    override def keyPressed (e: KeyEvent): Unit = apply(0, e)
    override def keyReleased(e: KeyEvent): Unit = apply(1, e)
    override def keyTyped   (e: KeyEvent): Unit = apply(2, e)
  }
}
f.setSize(200, 200)
f.setVisible(true)
p.requestFocus()
```

When I *press down* the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, it is reported as such. But as soon as I press the additional key, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, both the pressed, typed and released modifier mask is simply changed to <kbd>Meta</kbd>. If I release the additional key first, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the reported mask on <kbd>Alt</kbd> release is <kbd>Meta+Alt</kbd>.

In any case, the expected behaviour is that <kbd>Alt</kbd> reporting is not changed at all. Since my development environment (IntelliJ IDEA) as well as many other applications make heavy use of <kbd>Alt</kbd> based shortcuts, I need to get this behaviour fixed. The bug is linked to the first setting (`Ctrl key position`), as soon as I disable it, <kbd>Alt</kbd> goes back to normal.

---

So is this a bug in Linux/GNOME? In OpenJDK (<kbd>Alt</kbd> still works normally in for example Iceweasel/Firefox)?

**Is there an alternative way to flip <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> without affecting the <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys?**

Comment: Actually, the issue is less severe, because having `Left Ctrl as Meta` gives little benefits. Cycling through applications can be done with `Alt`+`Tab` instead.